# Can an instance of a class replace itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in a global scope which is assigned an instance of a class like this:

```
window.someInstance = new MyClass();
```

At some point later, I need to replace that variable with a new instance, but is it possible/acceptable to do that from within a method of the class itself? For example:

```
function MyClass () {

    this.myClassMethod = function () {
        window.someInstance = new MyClass();
    };

}

window.someInstance = new MyClass();
window.someInstance.myClassMethod.call();
```

An odd scenario I know but it works cleanly, I'm just not sure if this creates any memory or referencing issues?

Comment: Overwriting a variable is not the same as replacing an instance - the instance can be stored in several places at once, such as variables or properties of objects.

Comment: Why do you have to replace it from the class itself?

Comment: You've got me writing bizarre code in my head now... `this = eval("new " + typeof(this) + "()");`... XD

Comment: Updating a specific variable from inside the class code is not my idea of working "cleanly". Also this means you can't create multiple instances of the class assigned to different variables because they'll all want to replace the same `window.someInstance`, so why bother having a "class" constructor rather than using an object literal? By the way, why are you using `.call()` on your last line?

Comment: .call() was force of habit. jQuery is used in the real code so I use .call() to keep this scoped to the class and not to the jQuery object

Comment: Hard to explain why I need to replace from within the class itself without going into a larger architectural conversation but basically another class can call a method that once run, requires a new instance be created. I could do that from the other classes by calling the method and then instantiating a new instance, but doing it this way means that instantiation only happens in one place - in this class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if everyone always accessess the instance indirectly via `window.somereference`. As soon as anyone does `var x = window.someinstance` then you lose the indirection and your trick would stop working.

You might acheieve a more robust implementation by placing the indirection in a variable of the instance itself instead of in a global variable

```
function Instance(){
   this.impl = ...;
}
Instance.prototype = {
    changeImpl: function(){ this.impl = new Impl(); },

    //delegate all other methods
    f1: function(){ return this.impl.f1(); }
}
```

Comment: Individual properties of the original object could be referenced externally as well.

Comment: I have control of the access so that's fine. Thanks for the suggestion too